# Cannot find the node called texture coordinate in blender 2.79?

Tags: texture-coordinates

I'm following a tutorial and in my node editor I don't have the texture coordinate node. I'm using blender 2.79, any idea where it is or what replaces it?

Answer (score 3):

Since Blender render (internal) is missing that (shader) node, I guess you have maybe not set Cycles as render engine:

[image]